# Unable to update mySQL dynamically for Numeric & string values

Tags: php, mysql

```
$colName = $this->input->post('colName');
$value = $this->input->post('value');
$jobId= $this->input->post('jobId');

$this->db->query("UPDATE test set ".$colName." = ".$value." where id= ".$jobId);
```

I am able to update numeric values. However getting an error

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column '345drt' in 'field list'
>
> UPDATE test set TTDNo1 = 345drt where id = 41

How can I update numeric, string & date fields in DB?

Comment: `"UPDATE test set $colName = '$value' where id = '$jobId'"`

Comment: col `TTDNo1` has what datatype assigned in db, @VDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE test set ".$colName." = '".$value."' where id= ".$jobId);
```

Comment: it is updating in DB, however getting an error on browser as "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

Comment: I have previouly added "`" before column name as it safe: "UPDATE test set `".$colName."` = '".$value."' where id= ".$jobId.  Are you sure that your column name is "345drt"?

Comment: do you have field/column name "345drt"?

Comment: colName is "TTDNo1". Value is "345drt "

Comment: Echo your update query in browser & confirm that your value must be quoted I mean to say update query must be : UPDATE test set `TTDNo1` = '345drt' where id = 41 or UPDATE test set TTDNo1 = '345drt' where id = 41 or UPDATE test set TTDNo1 = "345drt" where id = 41

Comment: But i want to update numeric, string and date fields as well. Will it fulfil my all requirements? or i have to write 3 different queries?

Comment: Single query is ok....if you put quoted value, it will fulfill all your requirement.

Comment: Date field is not updating. And error for numeric & string (although it is updating in DB)

Comment: echo the update query in browser, so it will easy to find out the error.

Comment: UPDATE test set TTDNo1 = '56ttt' where id = 41

Comment: It should work...there is no issue in this query if & only if the column name TTDNo1 is your column name in database...in this case what error you get?

Comment: Also post your table schema

Comment: As mentioned earlier, it updates in DB, however getting an error on browser as "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

Comment: try to omit  "`"  character

Comment: http://localhost/testApp/index.php/%3C!?php%20echo%20site_url(%27Search/updateData%27);%20?%3E---- What is this? Why system calls link/URL  like this?

Comment: what you want?set server path in host file.Also this is not related to this post...create different question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE test set ".$colName." = '".$value."' where id= ".$jobId);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unknown column '345drt' in 'field list'

it looks you have wrong value for column name, you put the value in the column name try to print the value of $colName and $value befor exute the query 
and do the query as @Dipanwita Kundu did

Comment: colName is "TTDNo1". Value is "345drt"

Comment: echo "UPDATE test set ".$colName." = ".$value." where id= ".$jobId;
paste the result of this echo in comments here'

Comment: the query should be like this
**"UPDATE test set " . $colName . " = '" . $value . "' where id= " . $jobId;**
and the echo value is 
**UPDATE test set TTDNo1 = '345drt' where id= 41**

Comment: UPDATE test set TTDNo1 = '56ttt' where id = 41

Answer (score 0):

Since the Column is **varchar**, you should try *concatenating* your variables :

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE test set ".$colName." = '".$value."' where id= '".$jobId."' ");
```

Comment: @VDS, did the answer solved your issue. Please accept any answer that solved your issue. So will be helpful for other users as well